# How to add a message text from telegram user to Database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, telegram-bot

i'm writing a TG bot that gets information from a user and sends it to another chat. I stuck on the task where I need to add data from a user's massage to database and I can't find proper solution for it(yes i googled how to do it, but found nothing I can understand)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYZAN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjfs9.png)

here is a bot code

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import logging
from config import Database


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token="***")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('db1')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_init(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    kb = types.KeyboardButton(text="Добавить объявление")
    markup.add(kb)
    await message.answer("Добро Пожаловать", reply_markup=markup)


async  def add_titl(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Добавить объявление":
        await message.answer( text="Добавьте название позиции")
        link = message.text
        with open(link, "wb") as save_file:
                save_file.write(bot.download_file(message.from_user.id, message.text[0]))
                data = [(message.text, str(message.from_user.username))]
                db.add_title(data)`
```

here is a DB code

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self, db1):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db1)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_init(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' =?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,))


    def add_text(self, an_text):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'ann_cont' ('an_text') VALUES(?)", (an_text,))

    def add_title(self, ann_tit):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'ann_cont' ('ann_tit') VALUES(?)", (ann_tit,))

    def add_price(self, an_price):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'ann_cont' ('an_price') VALUES(?)", (an_price,))

    def add_pic(self, an_ph):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'ann_cont' ('an_ph') VALUES(?)", (an_ph,))
```

Comment: You probably forgot to register `add_titl` as message handler: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html#aiogram.Dispatcher.register_message_handler or via decorator https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html#aiogram.Dispatcher.message_handler